# Label for a button to kick work back to previous user

Tags: buttons, actions

We have a process in which a piece of work needs to be submitted by one user, approved by a second user and finalised by a third. Either of the last two users can send the work back to the first for revision and resubmission, so labelling the action button "Reject" has too much of a sense of finality (we use a Reject button for activities that are terminated)

Currently the button is labelled "Revise", but my feeling is that this gives too much of a sense that the action from the button is to allow the current user to revise the work, rather than returning it to the previous user for revision.

Any thoughts on what a more appropriate label would be?

Comment: Can the second or third individual make comments on what needs to be corrected and how?

Comment: Welcome to the site, @Daniel!  I'm voting to close this question as opinion-based because it seems likely to solicit various different, brief answers with little evidence for each.  (A question that would be more likely to remain open would be to ask about the process of coming up with a term to use in a situation like this.) Also, have you considered just labeling the button with the natural language you've used in your post here: "Send Back"?

Comment: @BDD Yes, there is a comments field for corrections to be made.

Answer (score 2):

'Reassign' :

- Step 1 : Click on reassign
- Step 2 : select the user who needs to revise the work. Make comment or remarks box.
- Step 3 : Build an activity log. Always helps.

Answer (score 1):

### Iterate

Iteration is the name of the game especially in today's agile world.  I like this word because it is neutral and less judgmental than **Unapprove**, **Deny**, or **Reject**.

From a UX standpoint it is more important that your users know what clicking the button will do *before* they click it.  Inline help text is a great way to reassure the user.

[image: iterate]

Answer (score 0):

I would label it as `Send Back` and then above the area they can make comments, I would put something along the lines of `Suggested Revisions`. So depending on your design, it would look something like this:

[image: Potential Mockup]

This would let the reviewer know that it will get sent back to the original person with their revisions attached.